# Listen to unix socket in sailsjs

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I know it's pretty easy and possible to listen to a unix socket file in express mvc. But in sailsjs, I do not know where and how to do this due to lack of documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're referring to the ability of Express to bind to a Unix domain socket rather than a port, you can accomplish the same with Sails by setting the `port` config, either on Sails lift:

```
sails lift --port=/tmp/sails.sock
```

or in your `/config/local.js`

```
port: '/tmp/sails.sock'
```

Then you could `telnet /tmp/sails.sock` with Sails running to test it out!