# Sails.js lift via Unix Socket

Tags: sails.js

Does sails.js have a way to lift the server via a unix socket on the filesystem?

I didn't see any documentation on how one would set this up, but I see that nodes http server has the capabilities for this.

http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_path_callback

Comment: possible duplicate of [Listen to unix socket in sailsjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394151/listen-to-unix-socket-in-sailsjs)

Comment: Thanks, I must have missed this one. I think that addresses it.

Comment: @sgress454 Maybe this information can be added into the sails docs? That was the first place I was looking for it. Thanks again!